# sandboxd, pstopdf deny file-read-data and file-read-metadata

Tags: sandbox, cups

In attempting to get cups-pdf working in El Capitan, I'm running into the error that pstopdf errors out.

The system.log shows that the sandbox kernel extension is denying read access to the following files:

```
deny-read-data /Users/USERNAME/.CFUserTextEncoding
deny-read-metadata /Users/USERNAME/Library/Fonts
```

Is there a way to work-around this issue? What's the appropriate thing to do for sandboxed applications?